# CakePHP: unable to order by multiple criteria

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm on CakePHP and I've read [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#retrieving-your-data) on retrieving data and it clearly shows that multiple `ORDER BY`s are possible. However, I'm not able to get it to work. It works fine with just one, but when I change it to an array with two strings, neither seem to apply. What am I doing wrong?

```
private function _bundle_users( $report ) {

    $this->loadModel("User");
    $conditions = array(
        'ReportsUser.report_id' => $report['Report']['id']
    );

    //$order = 'ReportsUser.created DESC'; //THIS WORKS FINE
    $order = array( //THIS SEEMS TO RESULT IN BOTH GETTING IGNORED
            'ReportsUser.created DESC', 
            'User.last_name ASC',
            );
    $this->User->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('ReportsUser')), false);
    $this->paginate = array('conditions'=>$conditions, 'contain'=>array('ReportsUser', 'Attempt'=>array('order' => 'Attempt.created DESC'), 'Tag', 'Resume', 'School'),
        'order'=>$order
        );
    $users = $this->Paginate('User');
    return $users;
}
```

I think I'm doing exactly the same thing as [this example](http://www.cakephpexample.com/cakephp-basics/cakephp-retrive-data-multiple-order-priority/), with the exception of the `bindModel()`. Perhaps that's a relevant clue.

**Update1**

This works as expected: `$order = 'ReportsUser.created DESC';`

But this is ignored: `$order =  array('ReportsUser.created DESC');`

Seems like the array syntax is part of the problem.

**Update2**

The array syntax is also ignored when I use key => value format :`'ReportsUser.created' => 'DESC'`

**Update3**
Thanks to @Leonard, **this** works, despite what the docs say:

```
$order = 'ReportsUser.created DESC, User.last_name ASC';
```

Comment: *glares*, Cake eater.

Comment: According to the docs, **this is not** the way to go, but have you tried: `$order = 'ReportsUser.created DESC, User.last_name ASC';` ?

Comment: @Leonardo WHOA! that's totally *NOT* how it is supposed to work but it *DOES*. What gave you the idea to try that?

Comment: @SDP Just SQL logic, I'll add it as a answer then. I'm glad it worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs, **this is not** the way to go, but have you tried:

```
$order = 'ReportsUser.created DESC, User.last_name ASC';
```

?

Comment: It is preferable to use array order clauses than all in one string

Comment: Yes, it is still preferable to do that. There is nothing in cake that would prevent array conditions to be used so I suggest either checking your code for a hidden bug or making sure you are using the latest version of CakePHP. I Know that recently a bug was discovered when using order in paginate and having `$order` as a property in the model

Answer (score 1):

Not that proficient with CakePHP, but reading through the documentation, I'd give this a try:

```
$order = array(
    'ReportsUser.created' => 'desc',
    'User.last_name' => 'asc',
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually just tried this as well and it was ignored. See my update above regarding the array syntax.